# Getting the error "Unknown module in QT: positioning" in Qt Creator, when trying to run the SimpleBrowser example

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtwebengine

I bought and downloaded QtCreator and I'm trying to run the SimpleBrowser example:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html

When I build the project I get the error:

```
Unknown module in QT: positioning
```

I think the reason might be that I bought the Design Tools version of Qt Creator, and this module is not included in the Design Tools purchase.

Is this the reason for my error message? If I buy the Development Tools version of Qt Creator, will the error go away, and will my environment have the Qt WebEngine C++ classes, along with all it needs to build the SimpleBrowser example?

I tried adding Qt += positioning to my project file and it doesn't make a difference. Here is the project file:

```
QT += core gui
QT += positioning
QT += webenginewidgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11

HEADERS += \
    browser.h \
    browser.h \
    browserwindow.h \
    browserwindow.h \
    downloadmanagerwidget.h \
    downloadmanagerwidget.h \
    downloadwidget.h \
    downloadwidget.h \
    tabwidget.h \
    tabwidget.h \
    webpage.h \
    webpage.h \
    webpopupwindow.h \
    webpopupwindow.h \
    webview.h \
    webview.h

SOURCES += \
    browser.cpp \
    browser.cpp \
    browserwindow.cpp \
    browserwindow.cpp \
    downloadmanagerwidget.cpp \
    downloadmanagerwidget.cpp \
    downloadwidget.cpp \
    downloadwidget.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    tabwidget.cpp \
    tabwidget.cpp \
    webpage.cpp \
    webpage.cpp \
    webpopupwindow.cpp \
    webpopupwindow.cpp \
    webview.cpp \
    webview.cpp

FORMS += \
    certificateerrordialog.ui \
    certificateerrordialog.ui \
    downloadmanagerwidget.ui \
    downloadwidget.ui \
    passworddialog.ui \
    passworddialog.ui \
    downloadmanagerwidget.ui \
    downloadwidget.ui

RESOURCES += data/simplebrowser.qrc

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 3):

What a coincidence, we're trying to open the same project. I solved it by actually installing the `QPositioning` module using the maintenance.exe in the Qt Installation Folder (Typically in C:\Qt).

[image]